# Text from csv is cached on reload

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv, caching

I have created a html page of a list of info that's read from a csv file. The webpage is for internal use in my workplace and I can live with a few possible unhandled compatibility issues.
I'm using Chrome to get the page to work and I might address the IE/Edge compatibility issues late.

My problem is that when I edit the data in the the dynamically created table and the new data is saved and the page is reloaded (using php), the browser shows the date from before the edit.

How can I force the browser to reload with the updated file?

I've tried all the `<meta ***>` solutions I've been able to find and, as you can see in the php file, I've tried the php header solution. The only thing I've found to work is checking the "Disable cache" in Chrome's developer tool and this solution is not optimal with non tech savvy users.

The html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    <title>Some title</title>

    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssData.css">
</head>

<body onload='getData("")'>
    <div class='wrap'>
        <h1 id='createdDate' align='center'>Header</h1>
        <br>
        <div>
            <form action="phpFunc.php" id="some" name="someName" method="post" align='center'>
                <input type='button' id='edit' onclick='editData()' value='btn1' style='display:inline;' />
                <input type='button' id='add' onclick='addData()' value='btn2' style='display:none;' />
                <input type='button' id='save' onclick='saveData()' value='btn3' style='display:none;'/>

                <input type="text" id="tempText" class="someClass" value="Test" name="fileWrite" style='display:none;'/>
                <input type="submit" id='saveBtn' value="" class="submitClass" style='display:none;'/>

                <input type='button' id='cancel' onclick='cancelEdit()' value='btn4' style='display:none;'/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <table id='dataTable'></table>
        <br><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class='footer'>
        <i>Made by some guy</i>
    </div>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

The js function file:

```
var list = "", colNames = ["Kursus", "Image", "RAM", "SSD"];
var noCol = 4;

function getData(addon) {
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            visualFormating(this.responseText, addon); 
        }else if (this.status == 404){
            visualFormating("","");
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "Data.csv", true);

    xhttp.send();
} else {
    alert("Functionen er ikke understøttet i denne browser.");
}
};

function visualFormating(input, addon){
if(input.length > 0 || addon.length > 0){
if(list.length < 1){
    input = input.replace(/(\")+/g,'')
    var array = input.split('\n');
    var text = "";
    var temp = array[0].split(';');

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var temp = array[i].split(';');
        if(temp.length == 4){
        text += "<tr>";

        if(i != 0){
            for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){
                text += "<td contenteditable='false'>" + temp[j];
                text += "</td>";
            }
            text += "<td class='checkboxes' style='display:none'><input type='checkbox' id='check"+i+"'>"
        }else{
            for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){
                text += "<th onclick='sortTable("+j+")' style='cursor: pointer;'>" + temp[j];
                text += "</th>";
            }
            text += "<th id='delete' class='checkboxes' style='display:none'>Slet</th>";
        }

        text += "</tr>";}
    }
}else{
    text = list
}
}else{
    text = "<tr>";
    for (var i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++)
    {
        text += "<th onclick='sortTable("+i+")' style='cursor: pointer;'>" + colNames[i] + "</th>";
    }
    text += "<th id='delete' class='checkboxes' style='display:none'>Slet</th></tr>";
}

list = text + addon;
text = "<table>" + list + "</table>";
document.getElementById('dataTable').innerHTML = text;
};

function changeEditable(editable){
if(editable==true){
    var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=false]");
    document.getElementById('edit').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('save').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('cancel').style.display = "inline";
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxes');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        checkboxes[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}else{
    var editable_elements = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable=true]");
    document.getElementById('edit').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('save').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('cancel').style.display = "none";
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxes');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        checkboxes[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

for(var i=0; i<editable_elements.length; i++){
    editable_elements[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", editable);
}
}

function saveData(){
changeEditable(false);
checkDelete();
writeData();
clearEdit();
getData("");
}

function checkDelete(){
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var newList = "";

for (var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
    if (document.getElementById("check"+i).checked) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
    }
}
}

function writeData(){
var rows = document.getElementById("dataTable").rows;
var text = "";

for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++){
    var tempText = "";
    for(var c = 0; c < noCol; c++){
        tempText += '"' + rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML + '"';
        if(c+2 != rows[r].cells.length) tempText += ";";
        else tempText += "\n";
    }
    //var tempText = '"' + rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML + '";"' + rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML + '";"' + rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML + '";"' + rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML + '"' + "\n";
    if (!checkEmpty(tempText))text += tempText;
}

document.getElementById('tempText').value = encodeURIComponent(text);
document.getElementById('saveBtn').click();
}

function addData() {
var text = "<tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < noCol; i++){
    text += "<td contenteditable='true'></td>"
}

text += "<td class='checkboxes' style='display:block'><input type='checkbox' id='check" + document.getElementById("dataTable").rows.length + "'></tr>";

updateList(text);
}

function updateList(input){
var rows = document.getElementById("dataTable").rows;
var text = "";
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    text += '<tr>' + rows[i].innerHTML + '</tr>';
}

list = text;

visualFormating("", input);
}

function editData(){
changeEditable(true);

}

function cancelEdit(){
clearEdit();
changeEditable(false);
getData("");
}

function clearEdit(){
list = "";
}

function checkEmpty(input){
input = input.replace(/"/g, '');
input = input.replace(/;/g, '');
input = input.replace(/\n/g, '');

if(input.length < 1) return true;
else return false;
}

function sortTable(n) {
var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
switching = true;
//Set the sorting direction to ascending:
dir = "asc"; 
/*Make a loop that will continue until
no switching has been done:*/
while (switching) {
//start by saying: no switching is done:
switching = false;
rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
/*Loop through all table rows (except the
first, which contains table headers):*/
for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
  //start by saying there should be no switching:
  shouldSwitch = false;
  /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
  one from current row and one from the next:*/
  x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
  y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
  /*check if the two rows should switch place,
  based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
  if (dir == "asc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  } else if (dir == "desc") {
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
      //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
      shouldSwitch= true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (shouldSwitch) {
  /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
  and mark that a switch has been done:*/
  rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
  switching = true;
  //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
  switchcount ++; 
} else {
  /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
  set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
  if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
    dir = "desc";
    switching = true;
  }
}
}
}
```

The php file:

```
<?php
$file = 'Data.csv';
$fileWrite = '';
if(isset($_POST['fileWrite']) && !empty($_POST['fileWrite'])) {
    $fileWrite = urldecode($_POST['fileWrite']);
}
file_put_contents($file, $fileWrite);
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies.
header( 'Location: index.html' ) ;
?>
```

The csv is formated as follows:

```
"column 1";"column 2";"column 3";"column 4"
"Data 1";"Data 2";"Data 3";"Data 4"
```

If some info is missing please let me know. The whole 4 space to make code block is making a mess for me.

Comment: Did you try to load `Data.csv?randomnumbereachtime` ? The random number will force the browser to download a fresh copy every time.

Comment: No, I was hoping there was a way to just force the browser not to cache anything on the website. The random number would take some extra coding to make the website able to load the csv file on first load, wouldn't it?

Comment: What extra coding? Just add a random number, like : `"Data.csv?" + Math.random()` , job done

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. Easy and simple fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a random number, like : `"Data.csv?" + Math.random()` to your file name. It will force the browser to download a fresh copy each time.

Comment: But this will blow up the browsers cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can set, **when** the data is expired. Simplest trick is to use the past of timestamp(0). Add these two lines to your header code.

```
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
```